# Replace character if it follows with a number

Tags: php, regex

I have text:

```
$text = 'hello c8 world c test';
```

How do I replace the `c` character with `chapter` if `$text` contains the letter `c` **followed with a number**?

So we end up with:

```
$text = 'hello chapter 8 world c test';
```

So far, I have managed to replace `c` with `chapter`:

```
str_replace('c', 'chapter ', $text);
```

But this replaces *all* `c` characters. I suppose regex should rescue this?

Comment: You've already tagged this [tag:regex], have you, like, tried any regex…?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex and check what `c` has a following digit(s):

```
$text = 'hello c8 world c test';
$result=preg_replace("/c(?=\d+)/", "chapter" ,$text);

echo $result;
```

run it [here](https://3v4l.org/ZfFIl)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
\bc(\d+)\b
```

and replace with

```
chapter \1
```

Explanation:

- `\b` marks word boundary, to avoid replacements inside words
- `c(\d+)` finds `c` followed by digits and captures those digits for future use
- `\1` in replacement puts first captured group (digits) to replacement

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CkDoZX/1/)

E.g.

```
preg_replace('/\bc(\d+)\b/', 'chapter \1', $text);
```

Comment: This is perfect but does not work with `$text = 'hello v9c3 test ';`. How can I make it so that it detects `c3` there?

Comment: remove word boundaries`\b` - you can experiment in live demo I've linked